# Handling files with spring controller

Tags: spring, file, spring-boot, controller

**I need:** To download or show inline files from my filesystem through `@Controller`.

I've found serveral ways to do it. But, I'm confused which one is better...

I'm reading file like this:

```
public static byte[] readFileAsByteArray(String fileName) {
   ...
   return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName));
   ...
}
```

**Method 1 (Works fine):**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/help/manual")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getUsersManual() {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + MANUAL_FILE);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    byte[] fileBytes = FileUtils.readFileAsByteArray(MANUAL_FILE);
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<>(fileBytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
}
```

**Method 2 (Works fine):**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/help/manual1")
public void getUsersManual1(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.addHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + MANUAL_FILE);
    outputStream.write(FileUtils.readFileAsByteArray(MANUAL_FILE));
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

**Method 3 (Works only with "application/octet-stream" and attachment):**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/help/manual2")
@ResponseBody
public FileSystemResource getUsersManual2(HttpServletResponse response) {
    File file = new File(MANUAL_FILE);
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    return new FileSystemResource(file);
}
```

So, what is the best way to work with files in `@Controller`?

I use:

- Spring boot 1.5.9
- Spring 4.3.13

Thanks.

Comment: Belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer **Method 2** with a little modification.

What happened if the file size is huge, say for example a few gigs[GBs].

So you should read the file using `InputStream` and write it in servlet `OutputStream`. Otherwise you may caught `outOfMemoryException` because of heap space.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/help/manual1")
public void getUsersManual1(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String MANUAL_FILE="yourfileName";
    int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    // the complete absolute path of the file
    String fullPath = "path\\to\\your\\file";
    File downloadableFile = new File(fullPath);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(downloadableFile);

    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.addHeader("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + MANUAL_FILE);
    response.setContentLength((int) downloadableFile.length());

    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead = -1;

    // we need to write the bytes which we read from inputStream
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrote that you want to accomplish this by a @Controller, but have you considered a spring ResourceHandler which is IMHO the best way to serve static resources by spring?

Here is an example:
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources